# The meaning of "slow-boiling" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across a sentence in [an NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/12/movies/middle-of-nowhere-directed-by-ava-duvernay.html?_r=0)

> A plaintive, **slow-boiling**, quietly soul-stirring drama about a woman coming into her own, Middle of Nowhere carries the imprimatur of Sundance, but without the dreary stereotypes or self-satisfied politics that can (at times unfairly) characterize its offerings.

Most search results appear to be about cooking. I understand the word is used figuratively here, but what does it mean exactly?

Comment: It does not have an **exact** meaning. Figurative language does not denote, it connotes. What would it mean for a movie to simmer?  I am tempted to downvote. :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Great point... Thought some connotations might be more idiomatic than others so it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using cooking as a metaphor. If a pot of something is "slow-boiling", it's cooking, but it's not cooking rapidly. It's just slowly, slowly cooking the food.

The writer is saying that this movie is not an action-packed thriller. It's not car chases and shoot-outs. The story moves slowly but steadily to a conclusion.